# Safari app extension: contentBlocker(withIdentifier:blockedResourcesWith:on:), how does it work? how to get it to work?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

I am trying to save an extension that Apple is killing with their move to safari app extensions.

I am running OSX beta 10.15 and the latest Xcode beta.

There is a new API [contentBlocker(withIdentifier:blockedResourcesWith:on:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariextensionhandling/3238030-contentblocker)

But as with other related updates in this space the documentation is lacking.

Is there anyone out there that knows how to get that to function? 
Or is able to point me in the right direction?

Specifically, how does this work and how to get it to work?
Do I need to implement my own content blocker?
If so, then how does the communication between the content blocker and the safari app extension work / what needs to be configured to make that communication work?

Would be nice to have this tested before 10.15 actually goes live...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to first create a new target in the project for your Content Blocker. Then, in the `info.plist` for your Safari extension, under the `NSExtension` dictionary, add:

```
 <key>SFSafariAssociatedContentBlockers</key>
 <array>
     <string>BUNDLE ID FOR YOUR CONTENT BLOCKER</string>
 </array>
```

You can then add the `contentBlocker()` method to your `SafariExtensionHandler` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have since moved onto a different solution and cannot confirm this answer. If anyone else ends up here, another potentially helpful discussion can be found on apple forum [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121249)... doing Apple's documentation for them